# How do I drop off supplies at Hrothgar?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have the quest to bring supplies to Hrothgar, but when I got there I had no idea where to drop them off. Any idea what to do to complete the quest?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a small chest at the foot of the complex, before the stairs up. It is surrounded with bags and candles, etc.

Simply open the chest, search your inventory under Misc for **Klimmert's supplies**, place it in the chest, and close the chest.

You should get a quest update, and can go back to Klimmert.

Comment: Since this is a related point: does that chest ever fill up with locals' donations to the Greybeards?

Comment: @TheCommunistDuck all they donate is supplies. So, no, it will never contain anything valuable.